# Be notified when Cassandra write operation completed in Akka

Tags: scala, cassandra, akka

In [this Akka and Cassandra tutorial](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2013/07/31/akka-cassandra-activator/), an [integration test that writes to Cassandra and expects to read back the same data](https://github.com/eigengo/activator-akka-cassandra/blob/master/src/test/scala/core/TweetActorsSpec.scala#L21) inserts a 1 second delay between the write and the read. The delay allows time for the write request to be transmitted over the network and processed on the server. This is necessary because the [application calls `session.executeAsync`](https://github.com/eigengo/activator-akka-cassandra/blob/master/src/main/scala/core/tweetwrite.scala#L13) to send a request to Cassandra, and proceeds without handling the response from Cassandra:

```
class TweetWriterActor(cluster: Cluster) extends Actor {
  val session = cluster.connect(Keyspaces.akkaCassandra)
  val preparedStatement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO tweets(key, user_user, text, createdat) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);")

  def saveTweet(tweet: Tweet): Unit =
    session.executeAsync(preparedStatement.bind(tweet.id.id, tweet.user.user, tweet.text.text, tweet.createdAt))

  def receive: Receive = {
    case tweets: List[Tweet] => tweets.foreach(saveTweet)
    case tweet: Tweet        => saveTweet(tweet)
  }
}
```

Completing a write request usually takes much less time than 1 second, so the test can run faster if it instead receives a notification the write completed before attempting to read. How would you change the code to do this, while sticking to non-blocking I/O operations?

Answer (score 2):

[executeAsync returns](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/apidocs/com/datastax/driver/core/Session.html#executeAsync%28com.datastax.driver.core.Query%29) [java] [future](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/apidocs/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSetFuture.html) which you can wait on or attach some callback (thanks to the fact that it implements ListenableFuture from guava). General alternative could be using sync api from inside akka future.

Answer (score 0):

The official Scala driver for Apache Cassandra and Datastax Enterprise, with full support for CQL 3.0, is [phantom](https://github.com/websudos/phantom).

Phantom was developed at Websudos, official Datastax partners, explicitly to superseed all other drivers. It's being actively developed and maintained, with full support for all the newest Cassandra features.

To be "notified" of when a write completes, you would use the default api: `SomeTable.update.where(_.id eqs id).update(name setTo "test").future()`

This will return `Future[ResultSet]`, and when the future is complete so is the operation.